# Can a UILocalNotification ever trigger event beyond device on which code is running?

Tags: uilocalnotification

I released a beta that included some new UILocalNotifications that are set up like this:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = fireDate;
notification.alertBody = alertString;
notification.userInfo = @{@"userinfo":userName};
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

Now I am being told that someone not in the beta is receiving these messages. The only way the message is set up in the code above. Is there a way this could be presenting on user's phones when those users do not have access to the beta build?

p.s. Confident answers of 'no this cannot happen and makes no sense' would also be welcome.

Comment: No this cannot happen and makes no sense. :) On a serious note, the `UILocalNotification` class is for notifications on the user's device and just that user. It's even in the name (Local).

Comment: @TroyT. Much obliged but I wanted to be absolutely sure. This sounded like nonsense to me as well at the time but I was told I was wrong :)

Comment: So the non-beta version has no `UILocalNotification` code in it, correct? Unless there is some very very very odd communication built in the app, I don't see the possibility.